# How can I pass variables to command module's argv parameter in Ansible?

Tags: ansible, redis-cluster

I'm trying to write an Ansible role that configures [Redis cluster](https://redis.io/docs/management/scaling/).

The shell command that creates the cluster is:

```bash
$ /usr/bin/redis-cli --user admin --pass mypass --cluster create 10.226.2.194:6379 10.226.2.196:6379 10.226.2.195:6379 --cluster-replicas 1 --cluster-yes
```

I pass username, password, IP addresses of Redis servers and number of replicas as `extra-vars` in shell script

```bash
#!/bin/sh
ansible-playbook /etc/ansible/playbook-redis.yml -vv \
--extra-vars='redis_admin_user=admin redis_admin_password=mypass' \
--extra-vars='redis_cluster_members="10.226.2.194:6379 10.226.2.196:6379 10.226.2.195:6379" redis_cluster_replicas=1'
```

After reading [the documentation for the command module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/command_module.html) I wrote the following task:

```yaml
    - name: Create Redis cluster
      ansible.builtin.command:
        argv:
          - /usr/bin/redis-cli
          - "--user {{ redis_admin_user }}"
          - "--pass {{ redis_admin_password }}"
          - "--cluster create {{ redis_cluster_members }}"
          - "--cluster-replicas {{ redis_cluster_replicas }}"
          - --cluster-yes
```

But when I run it I get the following error:

```
"Unrecognized option or bad number of args for: '--user admin'"
```

which seems to be error of redis-cli that it doesn't recognize the argument.

I was able to get around the username and password by changing the task as following:

```yaml
    - name: Create Redis cluster
      ansible.builtin.command:
        argv:
          - /usr/bin/redis-cli
          - --user 
          - "{{ redis_admin_user }}"
          - --pass
          - "{{ redis_admin_password }}"
          - --cluster create
          - "{{ redis_cluster_members }}"
          - --cluster-replicas
          - "{{ redis_cluster_replicas }}"
          - --cluster-yes
```

This is not exactly nice looking, but at least it passes the username and the password, because the following task works:

```yaml
    - name: Get server info
      ansible.builtin.command:
        argv:
          - /usr/bin/redis-cli
          - --user
          - "{{ redis_admin_user }}"
          - --pass
          - "{{ redis_admin_password }}"
          - info
```

But now it can't get past the `--cluster create` argument:

```
"Unrecognized option or bad number of args for: '--cluster create'"
```

I also tried `- --cluster create "{{ redis_cluster_members }}"` and

```yaml
          - --cluster
          - create 
          - "{{ redis_cluster_members }}"
```

to no avail.

What is the correct syntax to run this command?

P.S.

The following task works correctly:

```yaml
    - name: Get Redis version
      ansible.builtin.command:
        argv:
          - /usr/bin/redis-cli
          - --version
```

and returns the version.

P.P.S
The following also works

```yaml
    - name: Create Redis cluster
      ansible.builtin.command:
        cmd: "/usr/bin/redis-cli --user {{ redis_admin_user }} --pass {{ redis_admin_password }} --cluster create {{ redis_cluster_members }} --cluster-replicas {{ redis_cluster_replicas }} --cluster-yes"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Got help](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/79967) from Ansible devs at GitHub. The reason for this behavior is how command module and redis-cli utility work with arguments.
`argv` adds delimiters when passing the command to the command line. So this:

```yaml
    - name: Create Redis cluster
      ansible.builtin.command:
        argv:
          - /usr/bin/redis-cli
          - "--user {{ redis_admin_user }}"
          - "--pass {{ redis_admin_password }}"
          - "--cluster create {{ redis_cluster_members }}"
          - "--cluster-replicas {{ redis_cluster_replicas }}"
          - --cluster-yes
```

turns to (mind the single quotation marks)

```bash
/usr/bin/redis-cli '--user admin' '--pass mypass' '--cluster create 10.226.2.194:6379 10.226.2.196:6379 10.226.2.195:6379' '--cluster-replicas 1' '--cluster-yes'
```

If you enter the above command directly you'll get the same error when running the task - `"Unrecognized option or bad number of args for: '--user admin'"`

This is because how redis-cli delimits arguments. From [redis-cli documentation](https://redis.io/docs/ui/cli/#string-quoting-and-escaping):

> When `redis-cli` parses a command, whitespace characters automatically delimit the arguments.

So, the correct command should be (note the single quotation marks)

```bash
/usr/bin/redis-cli '--user' 'admin' '--pass' 'mypass' '--cluster' 'create' '10.226.2.194:6379' '10.226.2.196:6379' '10.226.2.195:6379' '--cluster-replicas' '1' '--cluster-yes'
```

But for the Ansible task there is a problem - `redis_cluster_members` variable.
The solution suggested to me at GitHub:

```yaml
    - name: Create Redis cluster
      ansible.builtin.command:
        argv: "{{ redis_argv | flatten }}"
      vars:
        redis_argv:
          - /usr/bin/redis-cli
          - --user
          - "{{ redis_admin_user }}"
          - --pass
          - "{{ redis_admin_password }}"
          - --cluster
          - create
          - "{{ redis_cluster_members | split }}"
          - --cluster-replicas
          - "{{ redis_cluster_replicas }}"
          - --cluster-yes
```

It works, but I decided to use a workaround.
In `vars/main.yml` I defined a variable

```yaml
redis_create_cluster_command: >
  /usr/bin/redis-cli --user {{ redis_admin_user | quote }} --pass {{ redis_admin_password | quote }}
  --cluster create {{ redis_cluster_members }}
  --cluster-replicas {{ redis_cluster_replicas | quote }} --cluster-yes
```

For the explanation about `>` please read [this article](https://adminswerk.de/multi-line-string-yaml-ansible-I/), particularly the [second part](https://adminswerk.de/multi-line-string-yaml-ansible-II/).
The `quote` filter is for, as suggested [in command module's documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/command_module.html#examples), "to avoid injection issues". Note that it's missing from `redis_cluster_members` line because it too breaks the arguments.

The task itself:

```yaml
        - name: Create Redis cluster
          ansible.builtin.command:
            cmd: "{{ redis_create_cluster_command }}"
            creates: "{{ redis_etc }}/redis_cluster.created"
          no_log: true
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't test but I'm pretty sure you need to separate each cluster member in its own item in the `argv` list. The following is a bit ugly but should work.

```yaml
    - name: Create Redis cluster
      vars:
        argv_start:
          - /usr/bin/redis-cli
          - --user 
          - "{{ redis_admin_user }}"
          - --pass
          - "{{ redis_admin_password }}"
          - --cluster
          - create
        argv_end:
          - --cluster-replicas
          - "{{ redis_cluster_replicas }}"
          - --cluster-yes
      ansible.builtin.command:
        argv: "{{ argv_start + redis_cluster_replicas | split + argv_end }}"
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but unfortunately it didn't work, got an error "Wrong number of arguments for specified --cluster sub command"